# Control Manipulator/Gripper through EGM Communication ABB

Tags: ros, manipulator, ros-industrial, abb

I am a university student and new to robotics. I am part of a semester project where the goal is to directly control the gripper of the robot. The gripper is pneumatic and can be controlled with RAPID code. As of right now the ABB robot arm is controlled via EGM using the abb_libegm library and ROS nodes. My questions are, is it possible to send a bool value through ROS/EGM to simply control the gripper open/close state? If so, how? (I have poured over the documentation) If not, what is a recommended course of action? The desired outcome is to the the same controller thats guiding the egm to also open and close gripper. Thank you!